# No effect by sd parameter in arima.sim model parameter

Tags: r, arima, standard-deviation

I am new to R. I wanted to create an ARIMA(1,0,0) model which simulates data with the coefficient been 0.1. I used the following code:

```
set.seed(456)
## list description for AR(1) model with small coef
AR.sm <- list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.1, sd=0.0001)

## simulate AR(1)
AR1.sm <- arima.sim(n=50, model=AR.sm)

## setup plot region
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
## get y-limits for common plots
ylm <- c(min(AR1.sm), max(AR1.sm))

## plot the ts
plot.ts(AR1.sm, ylim=ylm,
        ylab=expression(italic(x)[italic(t)]),
        main=expression(paste(phi," = 0.1")))

print(paste('Mean:',mean(AR1.sm)))
print(paste('Std:',sd(AR1.sm)))
```

The std and mean of the data is:

```
[1] "Mean: 0.202367015812633"
[1] "Std: 1.03631583857173"
```

The problem is, no matter what I assign to the `sd` parameter (0.1, 1, 10), the standard deviation that is computed in the last line is about 1.
Why is it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `sd` is not part of `model` but needs to be specified separately. The following does what you want:

```
set.seed(456)
AR.sm <- list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.1)
AR1.sm <- arima.sim(n=50, model=AR.sm, sd=0.0001)
sd(AR1.sm)
```

I got this idea from the examples in the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/arima.sim) of `arima.sim`:

```
arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar = c(0.8897, -0.4858), ma = c(-0.2279, 0.2488)), sd = sqrt(0.1796))
```

As you can see, `sd` is outside of the parenthesis of the `model` part.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I read it from this source: https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/sec-tslab-autoregressive-ar-models.html, which seems to be wrong. Thanks